# SQL metastore not working in for hive in hadoop pseudo cluster

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hive

I want to execute sql queries in hive and hence I used *SQL* as metastore . But while executing I get the error:-

> **SemanticException org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient**.

I looked around but can't find the solution. 
Hive shell is running but while executing sql queries I get the error.
I took the help of http://hadooptutorials.info/2017/09/15/part-2-install-hive/ link.

*Hive-site.xml*

```
<name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName</name>
<value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value>
<name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName</name>
<value>hiveUser</value>
<name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
<value>jdbc:mysql://localhost/hive_metastore?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&amp;useSSL=false</value>
<name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword</name>
<value>hiveUser</value>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the following property to resolve this issue:

```
<property> 
<name>hive.metastore.uris</name> 
<value>thrift://localost:9083</value> 
</property>
```